# Attachment Metadata not updated while uploading audio files

Tags: uploads, attachments, media-library

Suddenly, I am having some issues when uploading audio type of file in wordpress.

previously, when I uploaded .mp3 files, the attachment metadata of the files were updated accordingly, for instance; it was looking like something similar to

```
            array (
              'dataformat' => 'mp3',
              'channels' => 1,
              'sample_rate' => 44100,
              'bitrate' => 48000,
              'channelmode' => 'mono',
              'bitrate_mode' => 'cbr',
              'lossless' => false,
              'encoder_options' => 'CBR48',
              'compression_ratio' => 0.068027210884354,
              'fileformat' => 'mp3',
              'filesize' => 5070,
              'mime_type' => 'audio/mpeg',
              'length' => 1,
              'length_formatted' => '0:01',
              'title' => 'Notifier_Loud',
              'file' => 'notifier_loud.mp3',
            )
```

but not all of a sudden it has stopped working. Now when I am uploading any audio files, the metadata shows only text '1'.

I have no specific plugin installed and only uploading files thru normal media up-loader.
Also there is nothing in .htaccess which may create a doubt.

any clue is highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: What do your error logs say?

Comment: You mean the server error log? or wordpress log. Wordpress says nothing special but few core functions errors -> has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated.

Comment: I meant your server PHP log.